# Python datetime object and data into PANDAS dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a `list_of_data_lists` that consists of:

```
[datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 0, 49, 7), 26.3]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 2, 6, 24), 25.5]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 2, 36, 57), 26.7]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 3, 2, 49), 25.7]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 5, 26, 30), 27.9]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 5, 32, 4), 27.8]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 5, 50, 23), 23.5]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 6, 31, 3), 27.7]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 8, 9, 4), 26.1]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 9, 30, 40), 27.1]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 12, 27, 49), 26.5]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 16, 6, 10), 24.1]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 17, 21, 35), 26.3]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 17, 28, 54), 28.0]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 18, 4, 52), 26.7]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 22, 23, 24), 23.5]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 22, 51, 10), 26.0]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 23, 30, 14), 23.6]
```

And want to put this into `pandas` `dataframe`, under columns `date_and_time` and `data_value` for `data_list[0]` and `data_list[1]` in the `list_of_data_lists` correspond to. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, just pass `list_of_data_lists` to dataframe constructor

```
import datetime
list_of_data_lists = [
        [datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 0, 49, 7), 26.3],
        [datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 2, 6, 24), 25.5],
        [datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 2, 36, 57), 26.7],
        [datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 3, 2, 49), 25.7],
        [datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 5, 26, 30), 27.9],
        [datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 5, 32, 4), 27.8],
        [datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 5, 50, 23), 23.5],
        [datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 6, 31, 3), 27.7],
        [datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 8, 9, 4), 26.1],
        [datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 9, 30, 40), 27.1],
        [datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 12, 27, 49), 26.5],
        [datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 16, 6, 10), 24.1],
        [datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 17, 21, 35), 26.3],
        [datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 17, 28, 54), 28.0],
        [datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 18, 4, 52), 26.7],
        [datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 22, 23, 24), 23.5],
        [datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 22, 51, 10), 26.0],
        [datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 22, 23, 30, 14), 23.6],
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_data_lists, columns=['date_and_time', 'data_value'])

Out[155]:
         date_and_time  data_value
0  2019-12-22 00:49:07        26.3
1  2019-12-22 02:06:24        25.5
2  2019-12-22 02:36:57        26.7
3  2019-12-22 03:02:49        25.7
4  2019-12-22 05:26:30        27.9
5  2019-12-22 05:32:04        27.8
6  2019-12-22 05:50:23        23.5
7  2019-12-22 06:31:03        27.7
8  2019-12-22 08:09:04        26.1
9  2019-12-22 09:30:40        27.1
10 2019-12-22 12:27:49        26.5
11 2019-12-22 16:06:10        24.1
12 2019-12-22 17:21:35        26.3
13 2019-12-22 17:28:54        28.0
14 2019-12-22 18:04:52        26.7
15 2019-12-22 22:23:24        23.5
16 2019-12-22 22:51:10        26.0
17 2019-12-22 23:30:14        23.6
```

Comment: sigh! I think I just had a blonde moment - it seems so obvious now!~  Thank you :)